# how to attach a child process in gdb?

Tags: c, multithreading

My program spawns a child thread with execvp to run another program in xterm:

```
char *argv[] = {"xterm",
        "-e",
                "./anotherProgram",
        0
};

execvp("xterm", argv);
```

I know anotherProgram is running but in gdb, "info thread" doesn't show it. How can I attach the child thread and debug it? Thanks.

Comment: `execvp()` overwrites the process' address space. It doesn't create neither a new thread, nor a new process.

Comment: @H2CO3 However, `xterm` then goes ahead and fork-and-execs in order to run `anotherProgram` (which is the process that the OP is interested in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's sufficient for you to just find the process id of the child using `ps aux | grep anotherProgram` and then attach to it using a new gdb instance like this? `gdb ./anotherProgram <pid>`

If not, you could just patch the source code like this and recompile:

```
char *argv[] = {"xterm",
                "-e",
                "gdb",
                "./anotherProgram",
                0
};

execvp("xterm", argv);
```

I don't know a cleaner way to do this.